# XMLHttpRequest response type wrong in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I already checked most of answer here about a different response type in Firefox, but my case seems to be a bit different and I tryed already all fixes found here.

What I'm doing is to submit a from via XMLHttpRequest and response works fine in Chrome, Safari, Opera where I get a json object, but in FF I get the full document.

I have already tryed

```
1) xhr.responseType = 'json';
2) xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json")
3) xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
4) xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
```

There is no way to change the type of response.
Here below my code

```
function ajaxSubmit(data) {    
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "https://xxx.domain.com/sss/signup/";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");



var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);


//Handling response
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 


           if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

               var result = xhr.response;
               window.location = result.url;

           }
           else if (xhr.status == 400 && xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

               var resErr = xhr.response;
               showErr(resErr.error.fields);
           }
           else if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
 document.getElementById("errorContainer").innerHTML = xhr.status + xhr.response;
           } 
}
xhr.send(stringData);   
}
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using last one now => 49.0.2

Comment: You have a cors problem, see my answer and check

Comment: @Kalamarico — The question says "in FF I get the full document": This means it cannot be a CORS problem.

Comment: I think so too, we manage the other server with the endpoint and we set to accept some domains so CORS shouldn't be a problem. I get the response just in a format that I can't use.

Comment: you should take a look at the dev tools network monitor to see what the request and response headers are.